# Creating SQL logic - 7 day window

Tags: sql, logic, amazon-redshift

I am having a hard time coming up with a logic to write sql for what I want to do.

I am trying to create a "bill" column as the end result. For example, someone created a file on 9/1, made some edits in the first week, and then returned to edit the file on 9/10. When they returned on 9/10, that's billable because it's more than 7 days after 9/1. 9/15 is not billable because it's still within a week of 9/10. 9/17 is billable because it's 7 days from 9/10.

My struggle here is that there is a circular reference between the last billed date and the "bill" column. The "bill" column is conditional on "last billed date" and "days since last bill" but then I have to retrieve the "last billed date" based on the "bill" column.

Can someone please help? :(

[image]

Comment: Provide code for analysis.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Redshift?  They are not the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Redshift